# Unable to add objects into list on EventInput array, FullCalendar, Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I need to frame the object and give that to full calendar eventinput. But I am unable to generate dynamic object.

Here is my object:

```
import { EventInput } from '@fullcalendar/core';
...
events: EventInput[];    
this.events = [ { title: '', allDay: false, start: choosenStartDate, end :choosenEndDate, backgroundColor: RateColor.SpecialRate, borderColor: RateColor.SpecialRate },];
```

If I have multiple objects then I want to push in that array but I couldn't do it

```
let obj1:EventInput = { title: '', allDay: false, start: specialRateStartDate, end :specialRateEndDate, backgroundColor: RateColor.SpecialRate, borderColor: RateColor.SpecialRate };
let obj2 :EventInput= { title: '', allDay: false, start: normalRateFirstStartDate, end :normalRateFirstEndDate, backgroundColor: RateColor.NormalRate, borderColor: RateColor.NormalRate };
let obj3:EventInput = { title: '', allDay: false, start: normalRateSecondStartDate, end :normalRateSecondEndDate, backgroundColor: RateColor.NormalRate, borderColor: RateColor.NormalRate }
```

I am getting error as `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` when I try `this.events.push(obj1);`

It works if `this.events=[obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5...];` but I want then to inserted from a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud add **= [];** to array declaration:

```
events: EventInput[] = [];
```

Array is not initialized!!